# React application deploying with sub-domain is not working

Tags: reactjs

I am little bit trouble in my react application. I developed two seperate project in react one for front end and another for admin dashboard. Now I want to host them like following:

`www.example.com` and `www.example.com/admin`

Hence if I upload two different react project in subdomain it gives me 404 error and it should be. I used two separate project for two different design implementation as react can serve one index html only in a project. I googled a lot about this but can not taking in a final situation . If anyone can suggest me in a good way it would be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make some changes on your router.
I think this blog post would help you

https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1